# How to disable youtube background playing in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, youtube, background, phonegap-plugins

My app gets rejected by playstore "modify your app to make sure it doesn't enable background play of YouTube videos", I am using phonegap for android and it seems that the youtube videos are still playing even if my app is in background mode.

I have tried to set:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>
```

But still never worked, I even tried to add "pause" listeners for that issue, the listener is never triggered even though the "deviceready" listener is triggered.

Please I need some help here.

Answer (score 4):

Update the plugin to latest version (1.5.0) and use `shouldPauseOnSuspend` option set to yes

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://youtube.com', '_blank', 'shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes');
```

Comment: In which file do you suggest adding this line if you may?!

Comment: I assumed you were using InAppBrowser plugin to play the videos, how are you playing them?

Comment: well I updated that plugin and tried that option, still the same, the video audio is still playing in background, I was using window.location.href at first, but same result

Comment: @jcesarmobile does it work if i use iframe? I am facing hard time here. Tried almost all the answers from SO. No luck as of now.

Comment: You mean iframe in the inappbrowser or iframe in the cordova app?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775517/disable-youtube-background-playing-in-cordova-android basically iframe in cordova app.

Comment: @jcesarmobile I think you saved my day, you deserve a cookie :) thx a lot p.s.: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-violation-of-device-and-network-abuse-policy/145910/3

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, adding to jcesarmobile approach, we need also to add this flag in the preference "ShouldPauseInAppBrowser" and set it to true.

Thanks all

Comment: I don't understand, so what did you do?

Comment: you add "shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes" to the option of InAppBrowser and you add "ShouldPauseInAppBrowser" as preference in config.xml

Comment: you shouldn't need that preference, going to look into it, thanks