# How to fix background playing of YouTube video

Tags: php, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-desktop-app

I made an app, that plays YouTube videos.
Everything is working fine but when I tried publishing it to Google, it got rejected there.

The reasons are below:

> - Your submission has been rejected for enabling background playing of YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube API Terms of Service. If
>     this submission was an update to an existing app....
> - After a regular review, we have determined that your app enables background playing of YouTube videos, which is a violation of the
>     YouTube API Terms of Service...

So what I think what they are expecting is that when I hit the back button or lock screen button, the YouTube video must stop playing the audio and must pause. I searched here and tried this:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://domain.in/', '_blank', 'shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes,location=no,toolbar=no');
```

With:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false" />
```

When I'm checking in the PhoneGap desktop app, it is working as expected, but as soon as I build the apk and install on my phone the video keeps playing in background.

I am not sure what's wrong with. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable youtube background playing in phonegap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610560/how-to-disable-youtube-background-playing-in-phonegap-android)

Comment: Solutions was not working,  But now i have made it work as needed now.Thanks